# Frequently used comments

Tags: discussion, comments

Do you have any suggestions for comment templates that you frequently use to educate (new) users? The *close* modal has a couple, but I think there is room for more guidance before actually closing a question.

Comment: You might find this tool helpful once you've collected a few comments: [AutoReviewComments](http://stackapps.com/q/2116/38685)

Comment: @Murch wow, very cool, just installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### [Q] Chatty, open-ended questions

You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. [Chatty, open-ended questions](//$SITEURL$/help/dont-ask) diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

```
You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. [Chatty, open-ended questions](//$SITEURL$/help/dont-ask) diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
```

#### [Q] More than one question asked

It is preferred if you can post separate questions [instead of combining](//$SITEURL/help/dont-ask) your questions into one. [That way](//$SITEURL/help/how-to-ask), it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

```
It is preferred if you can post separate questions [instead of combining](//$SITEURL/help/dont-ask) your questions into one. [That way](//$SITEURL/help/how-to-ask), it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!
```

#### [Q] Duplicate Closure

This question will probably be closed [as a duplicate](//$SITEURL/help/duplicates) soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

```
This question will probably be closed [as a duplicate](//$SITEURL/help/duplicates) soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!
```

#### [Q] Self-Answering

Please don't place your answer in your question's post. It's totally okay to [answer your own question](//$SITEURL/help/self-answer). This will help users in the future who may face the same problems. Thanks!

```
Please don't place your answer in your question's post. It's totally okay to [answer your own question](//$SITEURL/help/self-answer). This will help users in the future who may face the same problems. Thanks!
```

#### [A] Answers just to say Thanks!

Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//$SITEURL/privileges) to [upvote answers](//$SITEURL/help/why-vote) you like, which is the $SITENAME$ Stack Exchange way of saying thank you.

```
Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//$SITEURL/privileges) to [upvote answers](//$SITEURL/help/why-vote) you like, which is the $SITENAME$ Stack Exchange way of saying thank you.
```

#### [A] Link-Only Answers

A link alone is not considered a [good answer](//$SITEURL/help/how-to-answer). Links may break and the answer becomes worthless later even if the linked material answered the question initially. At least if you [include a summary](//$SITEURL/help/referencing), the answer can somewhat stand on its own.

```
A link alone is not considered a [good answer](//$SITEURL/help/how-to-answer). Links may break and the answer becomes worthless later even if the linked material answered the question initially. At least if you [include a summary](//$SITEURL/help/referencing), the answer can somewhat stand on its own.
```

#### [A] Nothing but a URL (and isn't spam)

Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

```
Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.
```

#### [A] Requests to OP for further information

This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//$SITEURL/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.

```
This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//$SITEURL/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.
```

#### [A] Commentary as an answer

```
This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).
```

#### [A] OP using an answer for further information

Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

```
Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.
```

#### [A] OP adding a new question as an answer

If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//$SITEURL/questions/ask) button.

```
If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//$SITEURL/questions/ask) button.
```

#### [A] Another user adding a 'Me too!'

If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//$SITEURL/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//$SITEURL/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

```
If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//$SITEURL/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//$SITEURL/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.
```

#### [A] New user using answer as a comment

Welcome!  Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. Please ask your question by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. With a bit more reputation, [you will be able to post comments](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

```
Welcome!  Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. Please ask your question by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. With a bit more reputation, [you will be able to post comments](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).
```

#### [C] Too localized

This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

```
This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.
```

#### [EQ] Improper tagging

The tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//$SITEURL/help/tagging)

```
The tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//$SITEURL/help/tagging)
```

#### Credits

- Taken from the [AutoReviewComments tool](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) and improved them for Ethereum SE. Thanks @Murch for linking that.

#### Gist & Plain text

- Plain Markdown to copy+paste: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/5chdn/3c9cb4365a523fd53dd3dcb96eca57c3/raw/28971dc2e262d471359815948f1aebc6a6cd5cae/AutoReviewComments.md (editable [here](https://gist.github.com/5chdn/3c9cb4365a523fd53dd3dcb96eca57c3))
- Plain JSON-P to directly import from remote: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/5chdn/016ad2471e564d44ee242f242d58056c/raw/a3a8f5c563ca9abf48b4cad2e2eebc1b8012ed2c/AutoReviewComments.json (editable [here](https://gist.github.com/5chdn/016ad2471e564d44ee242f242d58056c))

Answer (score 4):

Comment template to address **link-only answers** with suggestion to improve:

> Please try not to post link-only answers. Could you consider adding
>   more details for instance on [suggestion]?

Examples:

- [Please don't post link-only answers. Try to add some details to your posts from the linked sources.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/trying-to-mine-alethone-on-osx-is-not-doing-anything#comment810_1070)
- [Please don't post link-only answers. Try to improve your post by explaining how it's done.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/complete-steps-to-write-a-hello-world-on-testnets#comment1448_1719)
- [Please don't post link-only answers.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/do-i-need-to-prepare-anything-for-the-upcoming-homestead-release#comment1759_2025)

Source: [5chdn](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/87/5chdn)