# questions on hold, comments explaining why

Tags: support, moderation, comments

I'm not familiar at all with the moderating part, reviewing question tool, so maybe this is irrelevant.

I just wondered if it is really necessary to write 4 comments all explaining 
the same thing to the author of an unclear question : [an example](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2668/delete-struct-entry-by-index-in-solidity)

Comment: Thanks for starting this discussion BTW!

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not necessary. Thanks for escalating this to meta.

**One good comment would have been sufficient**. The issue with that comments in that specific thread is that any later comment added another snippet of information for the author. My last comment was the most complete one.

As a moderator I always feel a little bit *guilty* after closing questions. And since my name is directly linked to the closing of the question, I always feel obligated to leave a comment providing the best guidance possible to educate the community and the poster about how to improve the question.

As you may have noticed, the important part of my comment is a link to the [help center](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help) of the Ethereum Stack Exchange site.

Related to the linked question are, probably:

- [Why do I see a message that my question does not meet quality standards?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error)
- [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)
- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

I would **always encourage** users to not only post a comment which requests improvement of the post but also -- if possible -- link related help center articles to educate the authors and the bypassing community about what could be improved.

---

PS. Also have a look at [Frequently Used Comments](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194/87) and feel free to contribute.

Comment: sounds fair to me. it would be amazing to have "shortcuts" to help on that, something like : "please rephrase blablabla and check #help1 #help2" and while we enter the # key it proposes various help topics. That maybe would be possible with a greasemonkey script.

Comment: Ah forgot to add that: [Frequently Used Comments](http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/194/87) started by Joris, feel free to contribute.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the first commenter. I'm just getting used to E.SE and will try to be clearer in future so that further requests for clarifications are not necessary.

Comment: It's cool. Just have a look at [Frequently Used Comments](http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/194/87).

Answer (score 2):

[Splice Struct Entry by Index in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2668/delete-struct-entry-by-index-in-solidity) was a good example of a question that should be flagged->"should be closed"->"unclear what your asking".

I suspect early commenters were not familiar with that feature, and if it had been done, moderator intervention would probably have happened earlier.

As an aside: the "should be closed" part is/sounds a little inaccurate, since it's actually just putting the question "on hold".  And the 2 step process, instead of a single "flag question since it's unclear what it's asking", probably also contributes to users not finding this feature.