# Creation of a new close-question reason/flag for "verify this work"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flagging, close-reasons

I don't know if new reasons for closing questions or raising flags can be added, but I was wondering how the community feels about questions such as [Is this a satifactory crowdsale contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24001/is-this-a-satifactory-crowdsale-contract) . I think I've seen three or four requests for, essentially, "does this code have bugs?" over the last few weeks and I don't think this is an appropriate use of StackExchange. We're all here to help people and/or receive help, but I think this is taking it a bit far. Questions similar to that, but *not* crossing the line, IMHO, include

- If I do *x* in my contract, are there any security risks I should be aware of? (More close-ended and doesn't require reading a whole contract)
- Does function *x* behave in this particular way? (Asking about language understanding)
- Is there a more standard way of achieving *x* than *y*? (Shows that you did some work and more close-ended)

Answer (score 6):

I agree. We should eliminate this type of question. If for no other reason that we wouldn't want to give bad advice. Plus--if we're giving advice of this type, we should get paid for it. Not sure if you can add a new flag type, but it would be helpful and more clear than a simple 'off-topic.'

Comment: We need to come up with that explanation text.  This is quite useful https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194/frequently-used-comments but unfortunately doesn't cover it...